# Are the digital pins in this schematics shown wrong?

Tags: schematics

The output from the phase detector H11AA1 going to Dig Out and the Dig In goes to the input of optotriac in the following circuit:

[image: Schematic]
<sup>[Image Source](http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/ACPhaseControlSchematic.png)</sup>

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the labels are intended to be relative to the device, not the Arduino. In other words, "Dig Out" means "Digital Output from the Sensor" and similar for "Dig In".

You would connect the digital output from the sensor to an input of a microcontroller or other circuit.

Comment: Is this the standard way? By the way J4 goes to Heater. Will the other end of Heater be connected to J1 (Neutral)?

Comment: @user16307 It's up to the designer, but generally you label things as what they are for, rather than what they connect to. (e.g. TX and RX for UART are labelled relative to the device not what it connects to).